# How to insert new object to the first index on array json api using Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

**I'm developing an app using Flutter so I have data from internet and I have json list array It depends on the news showing first Powell   I need when has new object instar to the index 0 How can I do this ???**

**this my function Call API**

```
Future<List<Hall>> fetchHall() async{

    String token =await read();

    final String url ='listhall';
    String Fullurl=Serveurl+url;
    var response =await http.get(Fullurl,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.connectionHeader:"application/josn ",HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:"Bearer $token"}
    );

    print('Token :${token}');
    if (response.statusCode==200){

         List<Hall> list =[json.decode(response.body)];
         list.insert(0, Hall());
      return list.map((m) => new Hall.fromjson(json.decode(response.body))).toList();

    }else{
      print(response.statusCode);

      throw Exception('Failed to load data from Server.');

    }
```

**my json**

```
[
    {
        "id": 42,
        "image_path": "https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1583971227.jpg",
        "hall_details": "*********",

    },
    {
        "id": 52,

        "image_path": "https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584390666.jpg",
        "hall_details": " Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you",

    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "image_path": "https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584453580.jpg",
        "hall_details": "Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you.",

    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation is ok, but it's necessary to convert the json data into a dart object first, try the next:

`final data = json.decode(response.body);
  List<Hall> list = List<Hall>.from(data.map((rawHall) => Hall.fromjson(rawHall)));
  list.insert(0, Hall());
  print(list);`

Comment: your code not working also I need to return like list to view on list view

Comment: Probably the error is in the Json data, you have to remove the extra "," at the end of the last value in each object, please look the code runing in: https://dartpad.dev/f1f5474a743991e4a62cb610374d481b